# Perform Calculations Within List Using Linq and Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following object:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 Id 
    public Int32 SampleId 
    public Int32 CompanyId 
    public Decimal Data 
}

public class Bar
{
    public Int32 CompanyId 
    public Decimal Data  
}
```

I have a list of these objects. I want to perform a calculation where I group the Ids by "CompanyId" first. Then for each company ID, add 3 different SampleIds Data together and returning a new object for each company.

```
//I want to get the data from SampleId = 2, 4 and 6 added together 
//from the Foo object and put into the Data of the new Bar object.
List.GroupBy(l => l.CompanyId).Select( x => new Bar { CompanyId = x.Key, ????? } );
```

I am stuck with how to perform the calculation after I do the grouping. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well what should the OwnerId be? And is it always SampleId 2, 4, 6? That sounds a little odd...

Comment: OwnerId can be any number. It's not used in any calculation so I just want it to be passed through. For each company, I want to add the Data for the same 3 SampleIds. Does that make sense?

Comment: Passed through from what though? If you've got three different samples, there could be three different OwnerId values. And what would you do if there were only 1 or 2 samples in a group? If there are more than 3 samples, how should you choose which 3 to use? There's a lot of context missing here...

Comment: You are correct, I am confusing myself as well. Let's just take out the OwnerID. I'll update the question now.

Comment: Seems you're very close to find solution. Try: `new Bar { CompanyId = x.Key, Data = x.Sum(a=>a.Data) }`

Comment: @Maciej I am missing the part that filters the SampleIds. I think that is where I am stuck. I feel as though I am making it more complicated that it really is.

Comment: So, do you want to group data by `SampleID` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look to be pretty close to me.

This should work:

```
    var list = new List<Foo>
                   {
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 15, Id = 1, SampleId = 2 },
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 10, Id = 2, SampleId = 4 },
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 25, Id = 2, SampleId = 6 }
                   };

    var output = list.GroupBy(
        l => l.CompanyId,
        (key, data) => new Bar { CompanyId = key, Data = data.Sum(d => d.Data) });
```

Or if you want to filter out just 2,4,6 as sample id (can't say I understand why to be honest) then this could work:

```
[Test]
public void Testing()
{
    var list = new List<Foo>
                   {
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 15, Id = 1, SampleId = 2 },
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 10, Id = 2, SampleId = 4 },
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 25, Id = 3, SampleId = 8 },
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 25, Id = 4, SampleId = 12 },
                       new Foo { CompanyId = 1, Data = 25, Id = 5, SampleId = 14 }
                   };

    var filterList = new List<int> { 2, 4, 6 };

    var output = list.Where(l => filterList.Contains(l.SampleId))
        .GroupBy(l => l.CompanyId, (key, data) => new Bar { CompanyId = key, Data = data.Sum(d => d.Data) });

    Assert.True(output != null);
    Assert.True(output.FirstOrDefault() != null);
    Assert.True(output.FirstOrDefault().Data == 25);
}
```

Comment: There are other SampleId values. Where would I filter those out? Should it be done before hand (before the GoupBy) or afterwards?

Comment: Just added that for you now, the filter list could be pulled from anywhere as long as its a list of integers

Comment: Now to throw a wrench into it. What if I wanted to have this formual instead of simply summing: SampleId1 + (SampleId2 * 2) + SampleId6? Can the query be manipulated to do something like that or would I have to  run my own loop over the data to do this? (I'll accept this correct answer regardless)

Comment: What is the actual formula needed? Did you mean to put SampleId1 there?

Comment: Sorry, SampleId2 + (SampleId4 *2) + SampleId6. Using the same 3 items is fine.

Comment: try this:             var output = list.Where(l => filterList.Contains(l.SampleId))
                .GroupBy(
                    l => l.CompanyId,
                    (key, data) =>
                    new Bar { CompanyId = key, Data = data.Sum(d => d.SampleId == 4 ? (d.Data * 2) : d.Data) });